# Baby started solids and stopped pooing. When should I be worried?

Tags: infant, solids

I've read that it's normal for babies to go many days without doing a poo once they first start eating solids. I'm just wondering

- at what point should a parent be concerned that their baby hasn't
  gone?
- Are there any signs that I should look out for?
- Is there anything I should be doing during this time?

Comment: My kids' pediatrician told us three days wasn't unusual, but after that, call. I'm not your kids' pediatrician, so if I were you, I'd call the office and ask before I trusted me.

Comment: Ensuring that baby gets enough (mother's) milk to avoid dehydration is important. Also helps get the poo going.

Comment: Thanks for the comments. Baby went just before-first time in 7 days. We'd been using diluted prune juice for a few days and giving plenty of breast milk and liquids.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Constipation in infants starting solid foods is not uncommon, and may not, in fact, be constipation. If your child is not uncomfortable (no obvious abdominal pain, crying, arching his back, attempting to pass stool without success), and is passing soft stool without difficulty every 5 days or so, it's fine.

If, on the other hand, any of the above are occurring, or if the infant is passing hard stool, you should mention this to your doctor. You can try adding non-absorbable sugars to his diet - pear/prune juice, pureed peas and prunes, and offer extra water as well as continuing breast feeding.

The [Mayo Clinic](http://www.mayoclinic.org/healthy-living/infant-and-toddler-health/expert-answers/infant-constipation/faq-20058519) has good information on infant constipation.

Answer (score 2):

My boy has gone a few days without pooing once or twice in his 8 months of life. I think up to 4 days at most.

We've asked doctors about it, and they say it's not unusual, and everything should be fine **as long as they are still passing liquids regularly**.

If you think about it for a moment, look at how fast your baby is growing, that size is coming from somewhere. My son is about twice the size he was when he was born.

My advice is, consult a doctor after 3 or 4 days of not pooing, **if they're still regularly passing liquids**. If they aren't, consult a doctor immediately.

Comment: My sons pediatrician said call at 24 hours and bring him in at 48 hours.  He was premature though so 3-4 days probably is more reasonable for most babies.